# Unable to use macros for MS Visual Studio breakpoint's condition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I cannot create a conditional breakpoint with a macro call in the condition expression - I am getting an error "The breakpoint cannot be set. identifier 'MY_MACRO_NAME_HERE' is undefined".

I know that the macro is visible at this line of code (this particular line includes a call to it).

Is there a way to invoke a macro within the condition, or is it simply not supported?

Comment: If you're talking about a C++ macro, macros do not exist beyond the preprocessing stage.

Comment: Yep I'm talking about a C++ macro. I was hoping VS is able to run the preprocessor on the entered expression.